# how to set grid element height as the rest of space

Tags: html, css, css-grid

In the example below - `navbar` is `27px` height and `top` is `auto` height;

Problem - if I have some content inside `story` - scrolling doesn't work. It becomes - content-height?

how to set `story` height  - as the entire rest of space from `divtop` to bottom of screen, so the scrollbar could work.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.navbar {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: lightseagreen;
  color: white;
  height: 27px;
}

.grid {
  position: fixed;
  top: 27px;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  height: calc(100vh - 27px);
  grid-column-gap: 9px;
  background: silver;
}

.grida,
.gridb {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
  background: gold;
}

.divtop {
  background: lightgreen;
  height: auto;
}

.story {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class='navbar'>NAVBAR</div>
<div class='grid'>
  <div class='grida'>
    <div class='divtop'>TOP</div>
    <div class='story'>STORY</div>
  </div>
  <div class='gridb'>
    <div class='divtop'>TOP</div>
    <div class='story'>STORY</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it is taking remaining height of the screen.. can you please show a screenshot

Comment: @XenioGracias, probably, but if I have some content inside - scrolling doesn't work. It becomes - content-height?

Comment: @qadenza you want story become scroll div when content overflow right?

Comment: @Saravana, when content overflow vertically - yes that's it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply I have added the `max-height` for your `grida,gridb` class based on your grid height. Comment for further information. I hope this solution will be helpful.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.navbar {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: lightseagreen;
    color: white;
    height: 27px;
}

.grid {
    position: fixed;
    top: 27px;
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    height: calc(100vh - 27px);
    grid-column-gap: 9px;
    background: silver;
}

.grida,
.gridb {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
    background: gold;
    max-height: calc(100vh - 27px);
}

.divtop {
    background: lightgreen;
    height: auto;
}
.story {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class='navbar'>NAVBAR</div>
<div class='grid'>
    <div class='grida'>
        <div class='divtop'>TOP</div>
        <div class='story'>STORY</div>
    </div>
    <div class='gridb'>
        <div class='divtop'>TOP</div>
        <div class='story'>STORY</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but height of `divtop` is not calculated?

Comment: optionally you can remove the `grid` height set for `grida,gridb` become `height: calc(100vh - 27px);` also.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple grid layout - because you are using a viewport-filling layout I guess you can ditch *fixed and sticky positioning* and *nested grids*, remove your *inner grid containers* (`grida` and `gridb`) and *wrap* it into a *grid container*:

```
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; /* two columns */
grid-template-rows: auto auto 1fr; /* three rows */
grid-auto-flow: column; /* place grid items in column direction */
```

Now you can use `grid-column: span 2` for the `navbar` - see demo below:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow: column; /* place grid items in column direction */
  grid-column-gap: 9px;
  height: 100vh;
}
.navbar {
  background: lightseagreen;
  color: white;
  height: 27px;
  grid-column: span 2; /* span both columns */
}
.grid {
  background: silver;
}

.divtop {
  background: lightgreen;
}

.story {
  overflow-y: auto; /* overflow of content */
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class='navbar'>NAVBAR</div>
  <div class='divtop'>TOP</div>
  <div class='story'>
    some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here
    some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text
    here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some
    text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here
    some text here some text here some text here some text here
  </div>
  <div class='divtop'>TOP</div>
  <div class='story'>
    some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here
    some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text
    here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some
    text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here
    some text here some text here some text here some text here
  </div>
</div>
```